# Chrome emulator not the same as iPhone - better emulator?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, emulation

Im building a mobile website and im not making it responsive. I am using media queries for each device. You may or may not think that is a good idea but I want to do it this way as the site is only 3 pages and very small and only accessible via mobiles.

My problem is that I need a good emulator so that I can adjust for the phones I do not own. I only have an iPhone to test and Chrome is not matching up. Is there a better emulator out there, or am I doing something wrong?

[Chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb5gG.jpg)

[Actual screenshot from iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hejkw.png)

Thanks.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Comment: You're using a separate media query for *every device in existence*? But there are thousands. Stop and do it properly.

Comment: Do you have this `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on the `head` of the document? Because Chrome device emulator worked great for me

Comment: To clarify the comment by @AlonEitan - the recommended `<meta>` asks the device to render the website based off its actual pixel width, rather than the pixel density which can sometimes cause a website to load as though you were zoomed out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I was redirecting from index.html using the following code:

```
if (screen.width < 765) {
            window.location = "http://www.myaddress.com/index2.html";
        }
```

Once I removed this code and made my index.html my mobile web site index file, the chrome emulator was the same as the actual screen.

I do not know why this happened. Somehow redirecting with the javascript has made the redirected address have a different viewport.

Answer (score -1):

Where is your css sheet? Add all of this to the bottom

```css
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 6 landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 667px)
  and (orientation: landscape)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 portrait */
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 667px)
  and (orientation: portrait)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 Plus landscape */
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 414px)
  and (max-device-width: 736px)
  and (orientation: landscape)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 Plus portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
{ }

/* iPhone 6 and 6 Plus */
@media only screen
  and (max-device-width: 640px),
  only screen and (max-device-width: 667px),
  only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{ }

/* Apple Watch */
@media
  (max-device-width: 42mm)
  and (min-device-width: 38mm)
{ }
```

Comment: Why would you have so many media queries for specific devices when you can make your layout work with just a few breakpoints? Makes no sense...

Comment: What does my stylesheet have to do with the question? Why is Chrome not emulating my stylesheet as it would if I was looking at it on my phone? That is the question. @Matti give it a rest. How about you answer the question or leave it be.

Comment: @Benjamin: Sometimes the correct answer is "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: those media queries satisfy all current devices out there, that's why and it's a tiny amount of code to add to make sure that your website works on any device that someone is trying to view it from

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen my iPhone 6 is viewing differently to Chrome's iPhone 6 emulation. Tell me why and Ill go and spend hours learning how to do responsive code.

Comment: @Benjamin: Because the iPhone isn't running Chrome, it's running Safari. It's also a different OS. And it has different text rendering, etc. The Chrome device emulation only sets a screen size and density, that's about it. It only gives you a general idea of the size of things. If you want to know what something looks like on an actual device, you'll need to look at it on the actual device.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen then what is the point of an emulator? BTW, im using Chrome app on my phone.

Comment: @Benjamin: I told you it's to give you a general idea of what your site would look like, and usually if your site is build correctly to adapt to all screen sizes (no fixed sizes where it counts etc), it gives you a good idea of the size of things on the real device. It is not, and it not meant to be, a pixel-per-pixel representation.

Comment: I didn't think it's an emulator as such in Chrome, it's just a responsive viewing mode. I have to agree with @MattiVirkkunen here